# Symfony4 Inject EntityManagerInterface into framework agnostic class

Tags: php, interface, symfony4, php-7, entitymanager

I try to create "framework agnostic" business class. That mean, my class should not have any reference to any framework class, only project dependencies.

I tried the following codes, with typehint in service.yml without success...

Here is my custom Interface :

```php
namespace App\Interfaces;

interface EntityManagerInterface extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface
{
}
```

Here my framework agnostic business

```php
use App\Interfaces\EntityManagerInterface;

class MyBusiness
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here my controller where I inject EntityManager :

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class testController extends AbstractController
{
    public function testAction(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $myBusiness = new MyBusiness($em);
    }
}
```

So I get PHP error for injecting the wrong class :

```php
Argument 1 passed to App\Business\MyBusiness::__construct() must implement interface App\Interfaces\EntityManagerInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /var/www/src/Controller/testController.php on line 7
```

How to inject properly the EntityManager to my framework agnostic business ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass the Doctrine's `EntityManager` which obviously doesn't implement your Interface.

I don't really understand the point on doing that, because not all Framework's "EntityManager" are the same.

But The first thing I could thing is making some sort of "`Adapter`" that will encapsulate the passed `EntityManager` in your own Class that Implements your own `EntityManagerInterface` and then pass it to your Business.